# How could I run the same code in every script?

Tags: ruby

I need to do the following steps in every script in my project. Is there any way to avoid copying and paste with Ruby? `parse_command_line_args` and  `read_app_config` are the methods mixed in with other module.

The following steps will appear in hundreds of scripts, I want to keep DRY:

## sample_1.rb (before)

```
OPTIONS = parse_command_line_args
CONFIG = read_app_config(File.dirname(__FILE__), OPTIONS)
APP_NAME = CONFIG["APP_NAME"]
DB_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../config/database.yml', File.dirname(__FILE__)))
DB = DbManager.new(DB_CONFIG, DB_CONFIG["COLLECTION"][APP_NAME], APP_NAME)
~~~~
```

## common_contants.rb

```
module CommonContants
 OPTIONS = parse_command_line_args
CONFIG = read_app_config(File.dirname(__FILE__), OPTIONS)
APP_NAME = CONFIG["APP_NAME"]
DB_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../config/database.yml', File.dirname(__FILE__)))
DB = DbManager.new(DB_CONFIG, DB_CONFIG["COLLECTION"][APP_NAME], APP_NAME)
end
```

## sample_1.rb (after)

```
    require 'common_contants'
    include CommonContants
    ~~~~
```

`parse_command_line_args`:

```
8:  def parse_command_line_args
9-    options = {}
10-    OptionParser.new do |opts|
11-      opts.banner = "Usage: #{self.to_s}.rb [options]"
12-      opts.on('-f', '--config file path', 'config file') { |v| options[:app_cfg_fpath] = v }
13-    end.parse!
14-    options
15-  end
```

`read_app_config`:

```
17:  def read_app_config(dir_path, argv=[])
18-    if argv.has_key? :app_cfg_fpath
19-      YAML.load_file(File.expand_path(argv[:app_cfg_fpath]), dir_path)
20-    else
21-      YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('./config.yml', dir_path))
22-    end
23-  end
```

Comment: create `module`, and just include it where you want.

Comment: Why cant you put these methodes in a file and in each script you want to use them you use the require or require_relative methodes

Comment: @jonsnow module doesn't work ``<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `parse_command_line_args' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: I think, you have to put `parse_command_line_args` & `read_app_config` method in your module.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn this part of your code into a `module` and us it anywhere you need.

> As you start to write bigger and bigger Ruby programs, you'll
>   naturally find yourself producing chunks of reusable code---libraries
>   of related routines that are generally applicable. You'll want to
>   break this code out into separate files so the contents can be shared
>   among different Ruby programs. Often this code will be organized into
>   classes, so you'll probably stick a class (or a set of interrelated
>   classes) into a file. However, there are times when you want to group
>   things together that don't naturally form a class.
>
> The answer is the module mechanism. Modules define a namespace, a
>   sandbox in which your methods and constants can play without having to
>   worry about being stepped on by other methods and constants.

Read more [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) and [here](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/037-issue-8-uses-for-modules.html)